# ¿Cómo escalar un contenedor de tal forma que también crezca y ocupe espacio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css3

Tengo un contenedor que quiero escalar ampliar y reducir (zoom in y zoom out), pero también que su forma expandida/reducida ocupe espacio en vez de solo superponerse sobre otras cosas.

Hay una imagen con la que hay divs absolutos que son puestos en coordenadas, estos deben retener sus posiciones relativas cuando se amplien o se reduzcan (por lo cual estoy escalando).

```js
var b = document.getElementById("outer");
var scale = 1;

function increase() {
  scale += 0.1
  b.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
}

function decrease() {
  scale -= 0.1
  b.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
}
```

```css
#outer {
  overflow-x: auto position: relative;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.pointer {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
}

#a1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}

#a2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}

#a3 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="increase()">Ampliar</button>
  <button onclick="decrease()">Reducir</button>
</div>
<div id=outer>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x350" />
  <div id="a1" class='pointer'>
  </div>
  <div id="a2" class='pointer'>
  </div>
  <div id="a3" class='pointer'>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  No cubrir
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las transiciones `scale` de CSS3 funcionan así. Desafortunadamente, al escalar, se sobrepone sobre otros elementos, ya que toma los contenidos del contenedor fuera del flujo creando un *contexto de apilamiento nuevo* (esencialmente colocando todos los contenidos posicionados *relativamente* al contenedor).

Mira este demo escalando todos los elementos por fuerza bruta:

```js
var b, scale = 1, offset, pointers;

window.onload = function() {
  b = document.getElementById("outer");
  offset = b.getBoundingClientRect();
  pointers = Array.prototype.map.call(b.querySelectorAll('.pointer'), function(e) {
    return {
      el: e,
      offset: e.getBoundingClientRect()
    }
  });
}

function increase() {
  scale += 0.1;
  scaleIt();
}

function decrease() {
  scale -= 0.1;
  scaleIt();
}

function scaleIt() {
  b.style.width = scale * offset.width + 'px';
  b.style.height = scale * offset.height + 'px';
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(pointers, function(e) {
    e.el.style.width = scale * e.offset.width + 'px';
    e.el.style.height = scale * e.offset.height + 'px';
    e.el.style.top = scale * e.offset.top + 'px';
    e.el.style.left = scale * e.offset.left + 'px';
  });
}
```

```css
#outer {
  /*overflow-x: auto;*/
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
.pointer {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
}
#outer > img {
  height: 100%;
}

#a1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}
#a2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}
#a3 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button onclick="increase()">Ampliar</button>
    <button onclick="decrease()">Reducir</button>
</div>
<div id=outer>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x350" />
  <div id="a1" class='pointer'>
  </div>
  <div id="a2" class='pointer'>
  </div>
  <div id="a3" class='pointer'>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
    No cubrir
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que tu imagen al ampliar no tape los otros elementos debes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var b = document.getElementById("outer");
var scale = 1;

function increase() {
  scale += 0.1
  b.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
}

function decrease() {
  scale -= 0.1
  b.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
}
```

```css
#outer {
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.pointer {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
}

#a1 {
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}

#a2 {
  top: 150px;
  left: 50px;
}

#a3 {
  top: 250px;
  left: 550px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="increase()">Ampliar</button>
  <button onclick="decrease()">Reducir</button>
</div>
<div id=outer>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/600x350" />
  <div id="a1" class='pointer'>
  </div>
  <div id="a2" class='pointer'>
  </div>
  <div id="a3" class='pointer'>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  No cubrir
</div>
```

Al agregar un `z-index: -1;` a tu `div#outer`, esto lo dejará por debajo de todos los elementos del sitio y así no podrá tapar ninguno.

Espero que te sirva, saludos !